# Script to mute audio in Linux from CLI works, but help needed

Tags: bash, shell, audio, command-line-interface, mute

I often stream news while I work and wanted to mute sound during commercials, so poked around and found this

[Stackoverflow thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/77522/command-to-unmute-and-maximize-volume)

which yielded some good things and resulted in the following script which works like a charm:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Mute, wait, unmute: attempt 1
for x in `amixer controls  | grep layback` ; do 
    amixer cset "${x}" on ; done
echo Mute for how many seconds?
read v1
sleep $v1
for x in `amixer controls  | grep layback` ; do
    amixer cset "${x}" 700% ; done
```

Which works but results in a godawful mess on the terminal screen: (just a taste)

```
<p>161 [~]$ MM<br>
numid=16,iface=MIXER,name='Master Playback Switch'<br>
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=1<br>
  : values=on<br>
Wrong control identifier: Playback<br>
Wrong control identifier: Switch'<br>
numid=15,iface=MIXER,name='Master Playback Volume'<br>
  ; type=INTEGER,access=rw---R--,values=1,min=0,max=127,step=0<br>
  : values=0<br>
  | dBscale-min=-95.25dB,step=0.75dB,mute=1<br>
Wrong control identifier: Playback<br>
Wrong control identifier: Volume'<br>...etc</p>
```

Which cleans up a bit with the addition of -q after cset

```
<p>166 [~]$ MM<br>
Wrong control identifier: Playback<br>
Wrong control identifier: Switch'<br>
Wrong control identifier: Playback<br>
Wrong control identifier: Volume'<br>
Wrong control identifier: Playback<br>
Wrong control identifier: Switch'<br>
Wrong control identifier: Playback<br>
Wrong control identifier: Volume'<br>
Wrong control identifier: Playback<br>
Wrong control identifier: Volume'<br>
Wrong control identifier: Playback<br>
Wrong control identifier: Switch'<br>
Wrong control identifier: Playback<br>
Wrong control identifier: Volume'<br>
amixer: Control default element write error: Operation not
permitted<br>...etc</p>
```

But why am I getting all of these "Wrong control identifier" messages?

I tried to `man grep` but then my head fell off and I had to tape it back on and now I have a headache. And I'm hungry.

Cheers
Omne

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
read -p "Mute for how many seconds? " v1 ; \
amixer controls  | grep layback | grep -v ' Ma' | 
    xargs -I '{}' amixer -q cset '{}' on ; \
sleep $v1 ; \
amixer controls  | grep layback | grep -v ' Ma' | 
    xargs -I '{}' amixer -q cset '{}' 700%
```

Notes:

1. The main trouble seems to be mixers like *'Playback Con Mask'* and
   *'Playback Channel Map'* were incompatible with the `amixer` options.  Using `grep -v` to filter those mixers out fixes that.
2. The `read` should go first, otherwise the *mute* lasts for the input
   seconds **plus** the time it takes the user to input them.
3. `xargs` isn't really necessary here, but it seems simpler than using
   a loop  with variables.
4. Those `; \`s  make it easier to copy and paste to the command line in one shot.  In a script the `; \` line endings aren't needed.

Comment: That worked flawlessly!  And I learned a lot from it too.  Besides asking other people to rewrite my scripts for me!  Hey, I've only been at this a month.

Comment: @OmneBonum, Glad to hear it was useful.  See also: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)